# Getting the kinematic equation $v^2=v_0^2+2a(x−x_0)$

Tags: calculus

As I've searched through the internet, looking for explanation. I found an answer with transformation of this formula:

$$
x = x_0 + v_0t + \frac{1}{2}at^2 ⟹ x = x_0 + \frac{1}{2}a(t + \frac{v_0}{a})^2 - \frac{v^2_0}{2a} 
$$
I don't understand how to get $\frac{1}{2}a(t + \frac{v_0}{a})^2$
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

You just have to complete the square. See that

$$\frac{1}{2}a(t + \frac{v_0}{a})^2=\frac{1}{2}a(t^2 + 2\frac{tv_0}{a}+\frac{v_0^2}{a^2})=\frac{at^2}{2}+tv_0+\frac{v_0^2}{2a}$$
and then

$$\frac{1}{2}a(t + \frac{v_0}{a})^2-\frac{v_0^2}{2a}=\frac{at^2}{2}+tv_0.$$

Just move backward.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$At^2+Bt=A(t^2+\frac{Bt}{A})$$

with

$$t^2+\frac{Bt}{A}=(t+\frac{B}{2A})^2-(\frac{B}{2A})^2$$

Replace $ A $ by $ \frac 12a $ and

$B $ by $ v_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that $a$ is constant, we can approach this problem alternatively as follows
\begin{align*}
a(s_{1} - s_{0}) = \int_{s_{0}}^{s_{1}}a\mathrm{d}s = \int_{s_{0}}^{s_{1}}\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}s = \int_{s_{0}}^{s_{1}}\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}v = \int_{s_{0}}^{s_{1}}v\mathrm{d}v = \frac{v^{2}(s_{1}) - v^{2}(s_{0})}{2}
\end{align*}

and the result holds.

Comment: For those more comfortable with differential calculus, one may write the first few steps as $$a=\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}s}=v\frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{d} s}=\frac12 \frac{d}{\mathrm{d}s}v^2.$$
If $a$ is constant, then this last expression is just $\dfrac{\Delta(v^2)}{2\Delta s}=\dfrac{v(s_1)^2-v(s_0)^2}{2(s_1-s_0)}$ as expected. (This is of course equivalent to the use of integral calculus.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formulation which gives a role to the average velocity. Let $v_{avg}:=\dfrac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}=\dfrac{x-x_0}{t}$ be the average velocity from time $0$ to $t$. Since this is constant-acceleration motion, we may use the kinematic equation for position to write
$$v_{avg} = \frac{v_0 t+\frac12 at^2}{t}=v_0+\frac{at}{2}.$$
By contrast, the kinematic equation for velocity gives the final velocity as $v=v_0+at$. As such, we may write $v_{avg}=(v+v_0)/2$---that is, the average velocity at constant acceleration is also the average of the initial and final velocities. Invoking constant acceleration once more, we have

$$a=\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}=\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta x}\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} = \frac{\Delta v}{\Delta x}v_{avg}=\frac{v-v_0}{x-x_0}\frac{v+v_0}{2}=\frac{v^2-v_0^2}{2(x-x_0)}$$
which is the desired equation. (Note how closely this parallels the use of the chain rule, which would apply even if $a$ weren't constant.)